# Coupon Code for First Time user in magento 2.1

Tags: magento-2.1, shopping-cart-price-rules, coupon

I have override the file - Magento-Checkout- Controller-Cart-CouponPost ,
 Using orderCount of the particular customer to check whether its new user or old , but no clue whereto put the condition.

Comment: You can set condition for use only once per coupon for each customer from admin

Answer (score 0):

You can see field for how many time user can use promo code.

See below reference screen shot.

[image]

Comment: I mean it should be applicable for newly registered customer